# Html and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the color of the "employee" field dynamiclly based on the "status" field valaue passed by php and js.

eg: if status field is 0 then empolyee field should be Yellow.

```
<form name="cubicle">
   <div>
      <tr><td><input type="text" name="employee" /> </td>
           <td><input type="hidden" name="status" /></td>
   </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function showDetails(var1) {
   document.cubicle.employee.value=var1;
}
```

Comment: Please give us some code and elaborate ur question little bit more

Comment: That really should be done in php, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `.style.backgroundColor`: http://jsfiddle.net/VvZZD/2/.

```
function showDetails(var1) {
   document.cubicle.employee.value=var1;

   var status = document.cubicle.status.value;
   var color;
   if(status == "0") color = 'yellow';
   if(status == "1") color = 'red';
   document.cubicle.employee.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using jquery you can do like this:

```
  function changeStyle(val) {
       $('.employee').attr('value')=val;
        var pos = $('.employee').attr('value');
        var col = (pos=='0')? "yellow" : "red";
      $('.employee').css('color', col);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a javascript method where you can pass the status value either 1 or 0 and then use " **document.bgColor** "method to change the color using if conditions...

you can take help from here: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/backgrou.htm
here dropdownlist value is selected... but you can use any control or hidden value...